# Eclipse maven plugin only download JAR package instead of AAR package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a simple test project with Eclipse (version 2021-06), and then run Maven build as "-e dependency:go-offline".

Note: I have synchronized the dependencies with Gradle before, all artifacts have been downloaded by Gradle. Now I just want to use that dependency in the test Maven project.

**Here is the test project pom.xml for reference:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>test_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    
    <name>test_project</name>
    <description>test_project</description>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.activity</groupId>
            <artifactId>activity</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Here is the activity-1.3.1.pom that maven plugin has downloaded in the local directory:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- This module was also published with a richer model, Gradle metadata,  -->
  <!-- which should be used instead. Do not delete the following line which  -->
  <!-- is to indicate to Gradle or any Gradle module metadata file consumer  -->
  <!-- that they should prefer consuming it instead. -->
  <!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>androidx.activity</groupId>
  <artifactId>activity</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <name>Activity</name>
  <description>Provides the base Activity subclass and the relevant hooks to build a composable structure on top.</description>
  <url>https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.3.1</url>
  <inceptionYear>2018</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>The Android Open Source Project</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support</connection>
    <url>https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support</url>
  </scm>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-viewmodel</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.savedstate</groupId>
      <artifactId>savedstate</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.collection</groupId>
      <artifactId>collection</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.tracing</groupId>
      <artifactId>tracing</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Here is the console output for reference:**

**From the console, I can see that maven plugin has downloaded the pom.xml file, it should know the packaging type is "AAR"!**

```
...
[INFO] <<< maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:go-offline (default-cli) < :resolve-plugins @ test_project <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] Downloading from mycompany-mirror: https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from mycompany-mirror: https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.pom (3.2 kB at 51 kB/s)
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test_project: Could not resolve dependencies for project test_project:test_project:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project test_project: Could not resolve dependencies for project test_project:test_project:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project test_project:test_project:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact androidx.activity:activity:jar:1.3.1 from/to mycompany-mirror (https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal): transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:831)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: transfer failed for https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar, status: 500 Unable to fetch artifact resource.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1204)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:831)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**But maven plugin keeps request the jar:**

```
https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.jar
```

**It should request the aar like this:**

```
https://mycompany.com/archiva/repository/internal/androidx/activity/activity/1.3.1/activity-1.3.1.aar
```

**Is there something configuration missing for the Eclipse maven plugin?
Why doesn't it download aar file? How to fix this problem?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare package type, default is `jar` if type is omitted.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>androidx.activity</groupId>
    <artifactId>activity</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

> it should know the packaging type is "AAR"!

No it shouldn't. Btw in very same pom.xml, do you see `<type>aar</type>` on dependencies ? It's there for same reaon.

Comment: But I don't need the packaging type in Gradle: implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1', Also, the maven plugin has downloaded the pom.xml file and it should already know the packaging type is AAR, thus, it should be no problem without declaring the type in the Maven dependency tag.

Comment: maven != gradle, although they use similar dependency mechanism

Comment: you should read more about maven. What `<package>` is declared in target pom.xml has nothing to do with what type you need. Dependency build can produce multiple attached artifacts (type) from single pom.xml - it has no idea what you want. Again, default is `jar`

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works. Thanks for your information about the maven build. Thanks so much!